# oracle index usage on database queries

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have got an audit table as below.

```
create table "AUDIT_LOG" 
         (  
            "AUDIT_ID" NVARCHAR2(70), 
            "PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID" NVARCHAR2(70), 
            "ACCOUNT_NUMBER" NVARCHAR2(100)
             PRIMARY KEY ("AUDIT_ID")
         );
```

I have below index

> 1. payment_idx on ("PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID")
> 2. payment_id_idx on ("PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID", "AUDIT_ID")
> 3. system_index on primary key AUDIT_ID

Below are query i am be using

```
Query1 : 
Select *  FROM
    AUDIT_LOG
 WHERE
    PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID = 
    'ID124'
    AND 
    AUDIT_ID<>'ecfdc2c3-87eb-48c9-b53c'; 

Query2 :
Select *  FROM
    AUDIT_LOG
 WHERE
    PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID = 
    'ID124'
    AND 
    AUDIT_ID='ecfdc2c3-87eb-48c9-b53c';
```

First query explain plan show the usage of index payment_id_idx having option BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED.

However second query explain plan showing usage of  system_index on primary key AUDIT_ID with option BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED.

**I was of the opinion that in the both query index payment_id_idx should be used.
Any idea why second query is not using composite index payment_id_idx.
Any help is much appreciated.**

Comment: "I was of the opinion that in the both query index payment_id_idx should be used" - why do you have this opinion?

Comment: Second query is using the primary key, so can't do better than use the primary key index to get the single row.

Comment: @TonyAndrews got your point

Comment: what is the distribution of values in the columns that are not primary key ? how many distinct values you have in those fields ?

Comment: @Mat as per my knowledge to use composite index we should  have similar column in where condition with correct order

Comment: @TonyAndrews in first query primary key is used still it is using index

Comment: First query has inequality (<>) on PK column, so the other index is more efficient (assuming not very high percentage of rows have 'ID124').

Comment: @RobertoHernandez there where fewer distinct values ideally less than 10

Comment: @recursion, then let me show you in an answer the reasons for that

Comment: @recursion, 10 distinct values for the column PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID ? and what about ACCOUNT_NUMBER ?

Comment: @recursion, I post an answer, feel free to comment there any question you might have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to simulate a scenario similar to yours.

```
SQL> alter session set current_schema=test ;

Session altered.

SQL> create table "AUDIT_LOG"
         (
            "AUDIT_ID" NVARCHAR2(70),
            "PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID" NVARCHAR2(70),
            "ACCOUNT_NUMBER" NVARCHAR2(100)
         );  2    3    4    5    6

Table created.

SQL> alter table audit_log add primary key ( audit_id ) ;

Table altered.

SQL> create index payment_idx on audit_log ("PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID");

Index created.

SQL> create index payment_id_idx on audit_log ("PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID", "AUDIT_ID");

Index created.
```

Now let's insert some demo data, but following some considerations:

- AUDIT_ID is unique in the form of `IDxxx` ( where `xxx` takes values from 1 to 1M )
- PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID takes 10 distinct values in the form of `LPAD` and a letter. The idea here is to generate 10 distinct values
- ACCOUNT_NUMBER is a random string of one letter and one letter in lpad to fill up 70 characters.

Thus

```
declare 
begin 
for i in 1 .. 1000000 
loop 
    insert into audit_log values 
    ( 'ID'||i||'' , 
      case when i between 1 and 100000       then lpad('A',50,'A') 
           when i between 100001 and 200000  then lpad('B',50,'B') 
           when i between 200001 and 300000  then lpad('C',50,'C')
           when i between 300001 and 400000  then lpad('D',50,'D')
           when i between 400001 and 500000  then lpad('E',50,'E')
           when i between 500001 and 600000  then lpad('F',50,'F')
           when i between 600001 and 700000  then lpad('G',50,'G')
           when i between 700001 and 800000  then lpad('H',50,'H')
           when i between 800001 and 900000  then lpad('I',50,'I')
           when i between 900001 and 1000000 then lpad('J',50,'J')
      end ,
      lpad(dbms_random.string('U',1),70,'B')
    );  
end loop;
commit;
end;
/
```

**First Query**

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly lines 220 pages 400
SQL> Select *  FROM
    AUDIT_LOG
 WHERE
    PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
    AND
    AUDIT_ID <> 'ID123482';   2    3    4    5    6

100000 rows selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 272803615

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |             |   100K|    20M|  3767   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| AUDIT_LOG   |   100K|    20M|  3767   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | PAYMENT_IDX |   100K|       |  1255   (1)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("AUDIT_ID"<>U'ID123482')
   2 - access("PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID"=U'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
              AAA')


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
      16982  consistent gets
       2630  physical reads
     134596  redo size
   12971296  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
      73843  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
       6668  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
     100000  rows processed
```

**Second query**

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly lines 220 pages 400 
SQL> Select *  FROM
    AUDIT_LOG
 WHERE
    PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID = 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'
    AND
    AUDIT_ID ='ID578520';   2    3    4    5    6


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 303326437

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |              |     1 |   219 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| AUDIT_LOG    |     1 |   219 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0076603 |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID"=U'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
              FFFFFFFFFF')
   2 - access("AUDIT_ID"=U'ID578520')


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          9  recursive calls
          6  db block gets
          9  consistent gets
          7  physical reads
       1080  redo size
        945  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        515  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed
```

The predicate information gives you a lot of information regarding the access paths:

In the first query:

```
1 - filter("AUDIT_ID"<>U'ID123482')
2 - access("PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID"=U'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
              AAA')
```

The access is determined by the "=" operator, and in this case a range scan of the index PAYMENT_IDX is the best approach. The filter comes for all the rows that match the access condition, filter those which are <> from the value in AUDIT_ID.

In the second query:

```
1 - filter("PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID"=U'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
              FFFFFFFFFF')
 2 - access("AUDIT_ID"=U'ID578520')
```

The access is by the primary key index, as you are using `=` as operator, so there is no better way to find the row that using the PK index. That is why you have an INDEX_UNIQUE_SCAN. The filter comes from the table access, as Oracle has already determined the row from the unique primary key index. Actually, that condition is not necessary as unless you look for 1 or no rows.

As in the first query, you are making a `<>` from the primary key index, Oracle will use the other index. assuming ( like in the example ) that you have very few distinct values. Keep in mind that in case it were to use the PK index, it would retrieve 999999 rows in the first step, then applying the filter, which is far less efficient than using the second index.

If you force the CBO to use the PK index, you can see it

```
SQL> Select /*+INDEX(a,SYS_C0076603) */ *  FROM
    AUDIT_LOG a
 WHERE
    PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
    AND
    AUDIT_ID <> 'ID123482';   2    3    4    5    6

100000 rows selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3265638686

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |              |   100K|    20M|   207K  (1)| 00:00:17 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| AUDIT_LOG    |   100K|    20M|   207K  (1)| 00:00:17 |
|*  2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN                   | SYS_C0076603 |   999K|       |  3212   (1)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID"=U'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
              AA')
   2 - filter("AUDIT_ID"<>U'ID123482')


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
     218238  consistent gets
      18520  physical reads
    1215368  redo size
   12964630  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
      73873  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
       6668  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
     100000  rows processed
```

Comment: Thanks alot for such a detailed response. I have one query What will be behaviour if ("PAYMENT_IDENTIFICATION_ID") have single.distinct value.

Comment: it would be the same. The best way to say thank you in SO is  to accept and/or upvote the answer, of course if it helped you.